# How to submit spark job from Airflow server to hadoop cluster

Tags: apache-spark, airflow

I have installed Airflow on a server. I'm able to ping from Airflow server to hadoop cluster. I want to submit a spark job from airflow server to hadoop cluster. Can someone list the steps I need to do for that? Do I need to install spark client on airflow server?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Livy can be utilized to submit spark jobs , take look at following blog post.[Spark Job submission via Airflow Operators](https://medium.com/@msreejith/spark-job-submission-via-airflow-operators-d5892f80ef9a)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to go about this is via establishing SSH connectivity between the Airflow server and (the edge node of) the Hadoop cluster. Now,
1. Create a SSH Connection from the Airflow UI (under the admin tab).
2. Use the above created connection in your Airflow pipeline via SSHHook.
3. Compose the spark-submit command.
4. Use the outputs of (2) & (3) in the constructor of SSHOperator.